# Send failed since rewinding of the data stream failed

Tags: unity, networking, server

I'm using WWW class to sent a WWWForm to an asp.net server.
it used to work in unity 5.3.x but since I migrated to 5.6.3f1, it is not working and sending `Send failed since rewinding of the data stream failed` message.
I tried doing it with the `UnityWebRequest` but it couldn't send the data in the form and I would get null values in the server side.
here is my code:

```
        WWWForm WF = new WWWForm();
        WF.AddField("UserID", ServerProperties.user.UserID);
        WF.AddField("UserEmail", ServerProperties.user.Email);
        WF.AddField("UserPassword", ServerProperties.user.Password);
        //I'm sending some json as strings. I don't need to do anything to the json data on the server
        WF.AddField("PlnFile", Export);
        WWW www =new WWW(ServerProperties.ServerAddress + "/Unity/SaveDesign", WF);
        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            yield return www.progress;
        }
        if (www.error != null)
            debug.Log(www.error);
        else
            debug.Log(www.text);
```

And I'm getting this request with `[HttpPost]` on the server.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveDesign(DesignViewModel _Design)
```

I'm reaching a deadline and I really need this, any ideas is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting this error in the future, your server might be configured to redirect some kinds of requests.
In my case I was requesting GET with an address like:"http://www.website.com/". AFAIK this should have worked for the POST requests as well, but it didn't, and after searching around I found this address to be working:"http://website.com/".
Maybe this is an obvious thing and I just didn't know about it. But anyway, this fixed it for me.